# Laravel routes, api and web use cases

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-api

I am trying to wrap my head around the use cases of web routes and api routes.

So far, from what i understand

1) **Web routes**, are used when we want to return views.

2)  **Api routes**, are used when we want to return json ( Api resource/collection ).

However both of these cases are referring to **GET** requests.

What about when we make a **POST** or **PUT** request, do we put these routes in **api.php** or **web.php**. Does it depend on whether the request is through an **AJAX** call ?

Additionally, i can't figure out in what cases should we use the **api** middleware and **web** middleware
By default, the **web.php**  uses **web middleware**, whereas the **api.php** uses the **api middleware**.

In the case where we are already signed in and we want to make an AJAX call, do we have to put that route in the **api.php** or **web.php**.

Do we use the **api** middleware only when we sign in using token based authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

Your same logic can be used to explain the use of `POST` or `PUT` requests for either types:

#### API routes

An API `POST`/`PUT` request would create/update some entity and return a JSON response, like a newly created model for `POST`, or an updated model for `PUT`.

```php
return response()->json($model);
```

This is useful in cases where you have javascript code calling an AJAX request. When you'd send data to your API endpoint, you should receive a status `200` with a JSON representation of the model you just created/updated. Your javascript code then decides what to do next, like closing a popup window.

#### Web routes

A web `POST`/`PUT` request would also create/update some entity but would usually return a redirect to a new page:

```php
session()->flash('alert', 'Model X has been updated!');
return redirect()->to('someurl');
// or
return redirect()->route('my.route.name');
```

`POST`/`PUT` Routes in your `web.php` are called using a simple `<form action="..." method="POST'>` form. Javascript is taken out of the equation here, so the form submission will send your form-data to the given endpoint, and it will return the response directly to your browser (which could be the view named `my.route.name`).